# Is there a way to add "hidden" data to a GCM (android push) notification?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to somehow add some data to the Android push notification by the server side?
So I can parse the added data in my app and do some actions related to it, like an Id or something like that.

Of course it must be "hidden" so the simple message is not the way I want it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course there is. Every piece of data you put in the message payload can be "hidden". As the developer of an Android app, it's your decision which parts of the payload are displayed to the user and which are not.

In the server side you decide which data you wish to put in the payload of the GCM message (inside the `data` dictionary), and you decide what to do with it in the application.

```
{ "time_to_live": 108,
  "data": {
    "message": "you can display this message",
    "id": "123456",
    "some-hidden-field": "some-hidden-value"
  },
  "registration_ids":["4", "8", "15", "16", "23", "42"]
}
```

Comment: Will this make the 'ping' noise? Basically- i want to send an 'invisible notification' that alerts the app that 'event X' has happened, without letting the user know about it.